# Google jquery json IP to location, etc. service?

Tags: api, geolocation

Does Google have any service that can turn an IP into a location?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3233767/how-to-load-google-clientlocation-api-without-loading-the-whole-google-maps-api

Comment: returns nothing on localhost, can it work on localhost? thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`google.loader.ClientLocation`](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples/source/browse/trunk/clientlocation/clientlocation.html).

`ClientLocation` has the following properties:

```
google.loader.ClientLocation.latitude
google.loader.ClientLocation.longitude
google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city
google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country
google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code
google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region
```

Comment: Yes, it should work as long as the client executing the script can connect to Google's servers.

Comment: is there a good link to read from google about why i or we cant connect to google servers ?